# How to run command then timer is ended ? C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, 2d

I dont know how to make a command run then the timer stops 
here is the code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Threading;
using System;

public class introtogamescript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public class Example
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // Create an instance of the Example class, and start two
            // timers.
            Example ex = new Example();
            ex.StartTimer(7000);
        }

        public void StartTimer(int dueTime)
        {
            Timer t = new Timer(new TimerCallback(TimerProc));
            t.Change(dueTime, 0);
        }

        private void TimerProc(object state)
        {
            // The state object is the Timer object.
            Timer t = (Timer)state;
            t.Dispose();
            SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If the timer is really just a delay you can do this way easier in unity, e.g. using `Invoke` or, if you need to pass parameters, a `coroutine`.

Comment: There are a couple of useful alternative implementation posted here already, but what is actually not working in the code that you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coroutines` like this:

```
public void  WaitAndExecute(float timer, Action callBack = null)
{
    StartCoroutine(WaitAndExecute_CR(timer,callBack));
}

IEnumerator WaitAndExecute_CR(float timer, Action callBack = null)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timer);

    if (callBack != null)
    {
        callBack();
    }
}


void Start()
{
    WaitAndExecute(5,() => {Debug.Log("This will be printed after 5 seconds");});

    WaitAndExecute(10,JustAnotherMethod);
}

void JustAnotherMethod()
{
    Debug.Log("This is another way to use callback methods");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start the timer use lambdas or anonymous delegate - this way you will have the timer as closure.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **Invoke(string methodName, float callDelay)**

Example:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
   Invoke("OtherMethod",3.5f);
}

//It should be called 3.5 seconds after SomeMethod
void OtherMethod()
{
    print(something);
}
```

And you can not invoke any parameter